# extracting numbers from string and removing the decimals and add it to the string back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string ="this is test 12.00 and 15.00". My requirement is to remove the decimals from the string .

My output should be "this is test 12 and 15". I have tried splitting the string and remove the decimals and replacing it however not working right. can some expert advise on this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the next regexp `/\.\d{0,}/g`
And with the `replace`function, you delete the decimal numbers.

Hope this helps :>

```js
let str ="this is test 12.00 and 15.00"
console.log(str.replace(/\.\d{0,}/g,''))
```

Comment: I would almost just use `{0,}` since we don't know all ranges of decimal values